# Release a group when the number of messages in the group gets to a number defined in an another line message

Tags: spring-integration

I have a batch process , and we receive an START message in a queue, and an END message in the same queue. After the Start message, we receive thousands of messages in other 3 queues, that we filter, enrich, aggregate and finally transform to JSON. We can call this pipeline as MAIN_PIPE )

After that Start message we have an adapter that reads from database the total number of elements in only one message that we will receive ( we can call this pipeline as COUNTER_PIPE )

And after the End message, whenever we have treated ALL the messages we have to send a request to an external service.

So, we need to count all treated messages ( JSON converted ) in MAIN_PIPE and compare to that number in COUNTER_PIPE.

How can I compare that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you mind to describe also how do you read from those `3 queues`? It isn't clear to me where is a correlation between START and all those messages to the batch. If that is regular message-driven channel adapter, there is a case when we may start receiving those message but there is still no START or no info about count in the DB.

Anyway I'd make it like:

1. The START and END messages, as well, as all messages in that batch must have the same `correlataionKey` to let an Aggregator to form a batch in the end.
2. Since the group in case is based on the `count` anyway, you don't have choice unless send to the aggregator even discarded messages from the `filter`. That might be just simple error stub to be able to distinguish them properly in the aggregator's release function.
3. The `releaseStrategy` of the aggregator must iterate over the group to find a message with the `count` and compare it with the group size + 2 (START & END messages).

Does it make sense to you?

Comment: You mean creating a custom releaseStrategy bean ?

Comment: So, yes. The item messages can appear before START message. Therefore only aggregator with full group scan can help you. The START message reads a count and comes to the aggregator as well. You don't release the group until an END is there as well. But you still have to check the group size and scan for the message with required size.

Comment: Of course, I mean even custom class for the `ReleaseStrategy`